# How to transpose data in one column to one row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have lot of data in one excel column separating by blank cells like this

```
Name     
email     
phone 1     
phone 2    

Name      
email     
phone 
fax
```

I need to put them like this..

```
Name       Name
email      Email
phone 1    Phone  
phone 2    Fax
```

Any body can help me? Please...

Answer (score 0):

If you start with data like:

[image]

and run this macro:

```
Sub reorg()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2
    k = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(k, j).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
            k = k + 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
            k = 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You will end up with data like this:

[image]

You can then delete the first column manually if you desire.

Comment: And I have another question...Any way to add blank row before starting large font texts in a one column?   I mean in a column there are mixed texts from large font and small fonts..Name is in large font,then next row at same column is email in small font,Like that then tele phone in small font..Then again Name in large font then e mail,Tele phone..I need makea blank row before starting large font to separate them..